# Spacing Issue Between Items in Horizontal Scrollable CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm building a collection view using **UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout** and want to scroll through its items horizontally. I'm having an issue where there is a large gap between some of the items when scrolling. In the image below notice the gap between UI/UX and the next item. How can I reduce this space?

[image: horizontal CollectionView spacing between items]

Here is `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` used by the collection view.

```
static func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
    return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (sectionNum, env)
        -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
        
        let layoutSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .estimated(100),
            heightDimension: .absolute(40)
        )
        
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: .init(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: layoutSize.heightDimension), subitems: [.init(layoutSize: layoutSize)])
        group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(10)
        
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
        section.contentInsets = .init(top: 0, leading: 12, bottom: 0, trailing: 12)
    
        return section
    }
}
```

Here is the cell the collection view uses.

```
class CellOne: UICollectionViewCell {
    private lazy var label: UILabel = {
       let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 25)
        return label
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        layer.cornerRadius = 8
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func configure(text: String) {
        self.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        label.text = text
        self.addSubview(label)
        
        let padding: CGFloat = 10
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
        ])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: .init(widthDimension: layoutSize.widthDimension, heightDimension: layoutSize.heightDimension), subitems: [.init(layoutSize: layoutSize)])
```

So we remove:  `.fractionalWidth(1)` and replace with `layoutSize.widthDimension`

The goal is to make the group and item the same size.

Comment: This makes all the cells stick to each other, there is no spacing between them.

Comment: But adding `section.interGroupSpacing = 10` fixes that issue.

Comment: Why do we have to make the group and item the same size? From my understanding, the group is a container for the items and we need to partition that space. With your solution, I'm guessing each item acts as its own group.

Comment: Yes, with my solution there is a group for each item. That is generally the standard approach. I have used and seen this in multiple diffrent apps. When you have simple layouts like the one in this question, you do not need any extra layout capabilities the group provides. The section partitions its space amongst the groups.

Comment: So you only have to use groups if you want to build something more complicated like the app store layout. Where in each section you might want to "group" items and display them differently. The photos app is another example of a more complex layout you would use groups for.

Comment: P.S please mark the answer as accepted if that resolved your question